# Removing table components in stargazer

Tags: r, formatting, tidyverse, stargazer

I am putting together tables using `stargazer` and presenting them in a HTML file using RMarkdown. Reproducible code to create the image is pasted below.

**I would like to remove the stars and standard errors associated with the constant** ("Alpha" in the image below).

I understand that I can manually overwrite the table components but is there a way that I can automatically retain stars and SE for everything but the alpha row? To re-write everything into character vectors seems a little cumbersome.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer) 

mdl1 <- lm(mpg~wt, mtcars)
mdl2 <- lm(mpg~disp, mtcars)

mdls <- list(mdl1,mdl2)

column.labels <- c('model 1',
                   'model 2')

covariate.labels <- c('Beta 1',
                      'Beta 2',
                      'Alpha')

keep.stat <- c('n')

stargazer(mdls, type = 'html',
          column.labels = column.labels,
          covariate.labels = covariate.labels,
          column.sep.width = "10pt",
          dep.var.labels.include = F,
          keep.stat = keep.stat)
```

[image: current output]

Comment: The usual caveat: you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point! Both alternatives seem great. Can either help me out with the question at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you asked if an alternative to `stargazer` could help you
with this. The answer is “yes”, [the `modelsummary`
package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) can do this
relatively easily. (Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

I say “relatively” because what you are asking is very idiosyncratic, so
I don’t think you should expect it to work out of the box in any
package. But here’s an example.

First, we start with a basic table with nice labels:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(broom)

models <- list(
    lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, mtcars),
    lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, mtcars))

coef_map <- c(
    "wt" = "Weight",
    "disp" = "Displacement",
    "hp" = "Horse Power")

modelsummary(models, stars = TRUE, coef_map = coef_map)
```

[image]

The [Customizing Existing Models
section](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-i)
of the documentation explains that `modelsummary` allows you to
overwrite any estimate (coef, standard error, p value, etc.) by defining
a new function called `tidy_custom.CLASSNAME`, where `CLASSNAME` refers
to the type of model object you are trying to summarize.

In our example above, we summarize `lm` models:

```r
class(models[[1]])
```

```
## [1] "lm"
```

Therefore, our customizing function will be called `tidy_custom.lm`. Say
your goal is to remove the standard errors, stars, and p values from the
table, but only for the variable `hp`. What we can do is overwrite the
estimates with `NA` (please refer to the docs linked above for a
detailed explanation):

```r
tidy_custom.lm <- function(model) {
  out <- tidy(model)
  out$p.value[out$term == "hp"] <- NA
  out$std.error[out$term == "hp"] <- NA
  return(out)
}
    
modelsummary(models, stars = TRUE, coef_map = coef_map)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! thank you